# Run installation on multiple Pi's - Epoptes

Tags: raspbian

I am busy playing around with [Epoptes](http://www.epoptes.org/) and it is a really cool tool to manage Pi's in a network.

I do have a question and can't seem to find a work around but has anyone been able to run an installation command across multiple devices on Epoptes? Essentially what i want to do is install Chrome for example on all selected devices (using one command) rather than installing them one by one on each device. If you were able to do this on Epoptes please share.

Comment: Two remarks...What makes this a Raspberry Pi issue? And wouldn't it be better anyway tp ask the developers (https://github.com/Epoptes/epoptes/issues?